# Customize material design datatable checkbox

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, material-design, material-ui

I just started using material-ui design with ReactJS. I am struggling to change a checkbox style that is being shown under `<TableRow />` component. ([Table component](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table))

I've already tried using `css` to style checkbox. It looks like material-ui has own checkbox logic using `div` and `svg` and hiding native `checkbox` element setting opacity to 0.

Any idea how it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

Material UI really does that. The native checkbox element does not accept many properties for styling, so for better looks it uses other elements. What you need to do  to customize a Material UI checkbox is to apply styles for those elements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant way to customize the checkbox in a selectable Table. However, you can customize the Checkbox component, as shown in the docs with heart icons and such. So, as a workaround, you could set your Table to be selectable={false}, and add your own custom column that contains customized Checkbox components. You'll then have to maintain your own selected state(s) and Select All functionality, if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It seems to me the only way to get it done as well. I was looking into a generic way to not change the entire logic. 
Could provide me a link where is that example with heart icon ?

Comment: Can't get URL from my current location, but it's in material-ui's docs, in Components -> Switches -> Checkbox